# I want to print random numbers from -100 to 100

Tags: java, random

I want to print 10 random numbers from -100 to 100, but my code below always print negitive number. I did not get any answer for this. How to do this ?

```
import java.util.Random;
public class VectorAndList {
public static void main(String arg[]){
    Random random = new Random();
    int number ;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    System.out.println(number = random.nextInt(100)+ (-100)) ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you calculate random number between 100 then you minus(100) that values thats why you received values  negative only.

so change like this

```
Random random = new Random();
int number ;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
System.out.println(number = random.nextInt(201)-100) ;
```

Comment: This will print only the positive numbers, range is -100 to 100

Comment: no ..based on possibility it gives negative ..example random number is 5 means 5-100 so result would be -95

Comment: yes, correct, it will

Answer (score 1):

Generate number from 0-100 and flip the sign randomly

```
Random rand = new Random();
int no = rand.nextBoolean() ? rand.nextInt(100) : rand.nextInt(100) * -1;
System.out.println(no);
```

alternatively you can use `ThreadLocalRandom` with negative range as well

```
ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int no = random.nextInt(-100, 100);
    System.out.println(no);
}
```